# Latex Template for a Popular Math Journal

Tags: latex

Can anyone offer a Latex template for a popular mathematics journal? It is easy to prepare a template for a technical journal with simple page layout but what I am looking for is something like the AMS Notices. A partial template I can work on or basic tips are also welcome.

Edit: Thanks for the answers but it seems I couldn't express myself clear enouh. I am *not* going to submit a paper to a journal. There is already mathematical magazine prepared in Indesign and I am trying to convince the editor to switch to Latex.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question; although it is too old to migrate to TeX.SE, that is where answers to this question belong

Answer (score 2):

Some journals provide class files and article templates for prospective authors, so possibly a good place to start would be to have a look at the submission guidelines pages for various journals.  [Geometry & Topology](http://www.msp.warwick.ac.uk/gt/), for example, provides a [public class file](http://www.msp.warwick.ac.uk/gt/macros/gtpart.cls) (which gives very similar results to the ones we use internally for producing the published versions) and an [article template](http://www.msp.warwick.ac.uk/gt/macros/gtlatex.tem) along with a page of LaTeX [good practice](http://www.msp.warwick.ac.uk/gt/about/journal/latex.html) advice and recommendations (more detailed documentation [here](http://www.msp.warwick.ac.uk/gt/macros/gtpartdoc.pdf)).  The template file is probably a good place to start, but will probably need a little alteration if you're using it for a different class file.  (Alternatively, a web search for "LaTeX article template" should turn up something.)

Edit: Oh, I see.  In that case, I guess you need to write a LaTeX class file which mimics the current journal style.  And exactly how you go about that will depend on what the journal currently looks like, but I'd be inclined to start with a class file that gives almost the desired results (the basic article.cls in the absence of anything more suitable) and then start tweaking it until it looks right.  Your original question seems to indicate that it looks a bit like the Notices of the AMS, but it doesn't look like they make their class files publicly available.  Be warned also that some serious TeX hackery (HaXery?) will probably be involved.

The other thing to bear in mind is that if the production processes are currently built around a system that isn't LaTeX then you might have an uphill struggle persuading the editor and production team to switch, unless there are clear and obvious advantages to doing so.  (I speak as someone who once wasted several weeks attempting, unsuccessfully, to convince a dyed-in-the-wool Fortran 77 programmer of the benefits of object-oriented programming.)

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://www.ams.org/notices/authors.html) AMS page, specifically the subsection "Preparation of articles for submission."